# Anypoint Studio v7.8 Runtime Compatibility with Mule Runtime version 4.4

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-studio, anypoint-platform

I am running into the following error running a Mule project (Runtime version 4.4) in my Anypoint v7.8:

```
++++++Failed to deploy artifact 'system-api', see below +++++++++++++++++++++
ERROR 2023-05-16 13:00:09,286 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer: Artifact system-api requires a newest runtime version. Artifact required version is 4.4.0 and Mule Runtime version is 4.3.0
org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: Artifact system-api requires a newest runtime version. Artifact required version is 4.4.0 and Mule Runtime version is 4.3.0`
```

I found that my project's mule-artifact.json file reads:

```
{
  "minMuleVersion": "4.4.0"
}
```

So, my guess is that Anypoint Studio v7.8 isn't compatible with Mule version 4.4? It doesn't seem to state it in the release notes (4.4 probably didn't exist when they were released). In order to run this project, I just need to update my Anypoint Studio to a version that can run a 4.4 project?

Comment: Please don't say Anypoint. There is a whole line of products that start with Anypoint. This question is about Anypoint Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommended: It is strongly recommended to upgrade to the [last release of Anypoint Studio](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/studio/anypoint-studio). You are using an old version of Anypoint Studio. Anypoint Studio 7.15 has been just released at the time of this writing. Your version was released originally in February 2021, it has been End Of Life for a time and misses a lot of improvements and fixes. You can still use Mule 4.3 with the newer Studio version [installing it](https://docs.mulesoft.com/studio/7.15/install-mule-runtime-versions) if not packaged with the new version.

Only if you absolutely need to stay in the old EOL version of Studio: You can edit mule-artifact.json to change the required version to a different one, like 4.3.0. Unless you are using a feature or connector specific to 4.4.0 then you should be able to run it with the previous version. There are no guarantees because as you correctly mentioned Studio 7.8 was released prior to Mule 4.4.

Not recommended: It *may be* possible to install Mule 4.4.0 into the old Studio version.